# Determining Feet Above Sea Level with IPhone

Tags: general-relativity, gps

I found a site on my IPhone that calculates how many feet above sea level my house is.  Initially, it indicated 986 feet above sea level, but then the amount of feet began to fluctuate.
Is this related to limitations of the website, or to issues related to the use of relativity?

Comment: IPhones have a pressure sensor, so perhaps it was using that, or GPS. Either can fluctuate. No relativity required (except for operating GPS satellites).

Comment: Without specifying what site you're talking about, it's hard to say what's going on here.